# pyspark ImageSchema.toNDArray raises AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I encounter a problem with new `pyspark.ml.image` features of Spark 2.3.

When using `ImageSchema.toNDArray()` in "local computation", it is OK.  But using it in an `rdd.map()`, it raises an error,

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'.

You can try the following code in pyspark with prepared pictures in the folder "jpg".  For example, I put [this single picture](https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg) in it.

In "local computation" it is OK:

```
>>> from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
>>> df = ImageSchema.readImages("jpg")
>>> row = df.collect()[0]               # collect() to a "local" list and take the first
>>> ImageSchema.toNDArray(row.image)    # so this toNDArray() is a "local computation"
array([[[228, 141,  97],
        [229, 142,  98],
        [229, 142,  98],
        ...,
        [239, 157, 110],
        [239, 157, 110],
        [239, 157, 109]],
        ...    
        ...
       [[ 66,  38,  21],
        [ 66,  38,  21],
        [ 66,  38,  21],
        ...,
        [ 91,  55,  37],
        [ 94,  57,  37],
        [ 94,  57,  37]]], dtype=uint8)
```

But if I put it in an `rdd.map()`, it will raise an

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

```
>>> from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
>>> df = ImageSchema.readImages("jpg")
>>> df.rdd.map(lambda row: ImageSchema.toNDArray(row.image)).take(1)

...
...

  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/image.py", line 123, in toNDArray
    if any(not hasattr(image, f) for f in self.imageFields):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/image.py", line 90, in imageFields
    if self._imageFields is None:
        ctx = SparkContext._active_spark_context
        self._imageFields = list(ctx._jvm.org.apache.spark.ml.image.ImageSchema.imageFields())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
        ...
        ...
```

This situation was tested and reproducible on

```
Spark 2.3.0 provided by Cloudera parcel
Spark 2.3.0 on Hortonworks
Spark 2.3.0 on Windows with WinUtils
Spark 2.3.1 on Windows with WinUtils
```

What was wrong?

How can I workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug of `pyspark.ml.image` because if I modify all the lines in `.../lib/spark2/python/pyspark/ml/image.py` like the following

from

```
ctx = SparkContext._active_spark_context
```

into

```
ctx = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

then everything becomes OK.

However, I am no expert in pyspark.  I think I'd better leave it open for discussion before I choose the answer.

P.S. I am not saying that it should be corrected in that way.  I just think it might be a bug.